# ¿Cómo puedo incorporar un botón en un correo escrito en C# a través del boby html?

Tags: html, c#, botón

Estoy tratando de realizar algo como esto:

```
        mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailmsg.Body= "<b>This is test</b><<br/><br/> <button id="test" type="button">Test</button>";
```

Sin embargo no lo reconoce cuando el antecedo un @ hago lo reconoce todo como solo texto.

Necesito saber cómo colocar un botón en mi código HTML en C#.
Agradezco la ayuda :/

Comment: Los botones en html no se ponen con <b>...</b>, eso es negrita. Usa <input type="button"> o <button...>

Comment: emmm eso lo se! <b> es para un mensaje aparte.. Ahí estoy mostrando que estoy utilizando el button y no funciona..

Comment: Has probado en poner en mailmsg.Body toda la página web completa? Vamos mailmsg.Body="<HTML><body><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"alert('hola')\"></body></html>";

Comment: Si ya lo probe no sale nada solo el nombre botón. [Botón]